# How can I detect incoming keep-alive pings on a C# gRPC server?

Tags: c#, grpc, keep-alive

According to the [Performance Best Practices](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/) from the official gRPC website keep-alive pings should be used to keep HTTP/2 connections alive.

These best practices for gRPC are also talked about in the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0#keep-alive-pings), with the following code example on how to create a gRPC channel with a keep-alive ping:

```csharp
var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler
{
    PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan,
    KeepAlivePingDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
    KeepAlivePingTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    EnableMultipleHttp2Connections = true
};

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001", new GrpcChannelOptions
{
    HttpHandler = handler
});
```

This works fine, but how can I detect those incoming keep-alive pings on the server? Can I use them in server-side code to detect if a connection to a client broke down? Are there other ways to detect connection issues in a gRPC channel?

It seems to me like those pings get frequently transmitted in the established TCP connection of the gRPC channel, but without any interface to access them like a "classical gRPC stream" would have.

Comment: Why not use your own state machine (Closed, Idle, Active states, for example), and your own Grpc calls to keep the connection alive? Then the server has its own state machine, and knows when the connection is broken.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first idea as well. But then I read in the docu about the built in keep-alive functionality, and thought I should do it this way. I also don't know how much overhead an additional stream is instead of using the built in functionality, if any. Ideally I can implement this as efficient as possible. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: There is quite a bit of information on "grpc keepalive," in my searches, and some was on stackoverflow. It is dependent on both the client and server software used, as to how it is supported (or how buggy it is). Apparently keep alive is to notice failures during a call, on the client side. You seem to be more concerned with the server.

Comment: Some believe you should not use keepalive at all: https://www.evanjones.ca/grpc-is-tricky.html